# How to use udp() in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, udp

I tried to use **`udp()`** in MATLAB with this code:

```
    u1 = udp('192.168.6.207', 8878, 'LocalPort', 8840);
    u2 = udp('192.168.6.207', 8840, 'LocalPort', 8878);

    fopen( u1 );
    fopen( u2 );

    a      =[ char( 240 ) ];
    fprintf( u1, a );
    recStr = double( fscanf( u2 ) );

    pause( .1 );

    fclose( u1 );
    delete( u1 );
    clear u1;

    fclose( u2 );
    delete( u2 );
    clear u2;
```

But I get **`63`** instead of **`240`**.

**How can I fix this?**

Any idea about my problem?

Thanks 
Hamid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `fprintf` and `fscanf` wrong.
You should do something like this:

```
a = 240;
fprintf( u1,'%d', a );
recStr =fscanf(u2,'%d');
```

Or, if you want to transfer only numerical values, you should use `fwrite` and `fread`:

```
a = 240;
fwrite(u1,a);
recStr =fread(u2,1);
```